# Weblogic server- Identifying the managed server status in Java code

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, weblogic, weblogic12c

I have some jobs that run in my application (These jobs created and managed by the application) and the application is deployed on a cluster of 2 managed servers.

We have distributed the load based on the even and odd number of the jobs on these 2 managed servers.
Now, we want to create the jobs if one of the instances goes down into the other instance.

How do we know if the other instance went down in Weblogic server cluster and my application is built in Java and spring.

Thanks

Comment: Is there something more specific you need that is not covered in the failover documentation? http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e24425/failover.htm#CLUST201

Comment: If you want to get server status in java code (JMX) see: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs90/jmx/accessWLS.html#1111297